# Dropbox + Mac Mini Server = Syncing Issues

Tags: mac, mac-mini, osx-server, dropbox, file-sharing

In our office, we use Dropbox business as a cloud; All of our files exist on a Mac Mini Server we use inside the office as a local repository for all of our Dropbox files. We then have Dropbox sync all of the files to and from the server. From there all of our macs selective sync files from Dropbox.

The issue? The Mac Mini Server seems to stop syncing randomly and then our files are scattered between Dropbox and the Mac Mini Server. Which makes it not a viable solution.

Does anyone know how to resolve these issues or what may be causing them?

Answer (score 1):

When it stops syncing run the utility "Activity Monitor" and check that both 'Dropbox' and 'dbfseventsd' are running.

Note that Dropbox runs on a per user basis so someone with Dropbox installed has to be logged in to the computer or Dropbox will not do its thing.