# Cannot connect to Mac Mini Server; Finder jumping around

Tags: network, finder, wifi, mac-mini, osx-server

I have a unique issue; while trying to connect to a Mac Mini Server on WiFi with my macbook the server shows up, but when I go to connect to the server Finder jumps the selection up to the top of the top left. No matter how many times I click, I can't get into the server. There are 7 iMacs that connect without issue.

Does anyone know why this error might be occurring?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the same server as in this [question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/95064/10733) if so I think there is a network configuration issue on the server which makes it drop connections. I would check the network set up of the server or even the network card itself.

Comment: This is specific only to this laptop, everything else that connects to the network is fine. It's not a network issue